# Require and place block in a drupal theme?

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-theming, drupal-7

In a theme I'm creating I'm wanting to place blocks in locations that are different from the default ones. Eg place the search block in the header.

Is there any way to do this from a theme: Be able to require a block and place it somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The theming system of Drupal is flexible enough to turn exactly that part of the page into a region where you want your block to appear. For this you need to add the region to the theme's `.info` file as described on [Assigning contents to regions](http://drupal.org/node/171224), e.g `regions[foobar] = Foobar`. This will make a new variable `$page['foobar']` available to your [page.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--page.tpl.php/7). You can then assign content to the region the same way as with Drupal's *builtin* regions.

If you want to circumvent this system and display a block ad-hoc, have a look at how [_block_render_blocks](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.module/function/_block_render_blocks/7) renders blocks.

Comment: It seems the script `if` statement is apart of only checks if this is the right page, and renders whats available. So if there is no menu, then there is nothing I can render

Comment: @TheLQ: I am sorry, I just noticed I linked to the procedure for Drupal 4.7 and 5.x. I updated my answer with the proper procedure for Drupal 6.x and 7.x.

Comment: Thats not really what I'm after. I'm wanting to have, by default, the search bar be in the header. The Drupal Powered By block in the bottom region. The user management block to be in another region. Etc. `_block_render_block` looks like an internal function for rendering them, which is something I don't want to call. Is there any way to set these defaults?

Comment: @TheLQ `_block_render_blocks` is indeed internal. The link to it was meant as a hint on how you could implement your own function that renders a block.

Comment: Why would I want to do that? Are you telling me that there is no way to do what a user can do in `admin/structure/block` programatically?

Answer (score 0):

It defeats the idea of configurable blocks but nevertheless it's possible: You have to create empty block templates for all but the allowed region. Or you provide/override the theme function for this very block and return nothing for prohibited regions.

Answer (score 0):

In D7 you can add a placeholder region in your themes .info file, clear the cache and put your block in there you can then output the region's content.

```
print render(block_get_blocks_by_region('region_name'));
```